# Kentico 10 Uniselector display custom field

Tags: kentico

I am looking for a solution to display a field of a pagetype in a uniselector.

My current setup

- Object type: **cms.document**
- Display name format: **{%DocumentName%} {% MyCustomField of
  MyPageType #%}**
- Selection mode: **Multiple**
- Where condition: ClassName = 'MyPageType' AND DocumentCulture = '{% LocalizationContext.CurrentCulture.CodeName#%}'

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can reference the field in the same way as `DocumentName` as long as you've added the custom field name to the uni selector's "Additional columns" field (you need to expand the Advanced options).

- Display name format: **{%DocumentName%} {%MyCustomField%}**
- Additional columns: **MyCustomField**

Comment: I tried this but I have this exception => Caused exception: Invalid column name 'MyCustomField'. The multi-part identifier "MyCustomField" could not be bound. The column 'MyCustomField' was specified multiple times for 'AllData'.

Comment: Yes, I see, I think you'll find this isn't possible then. You can tell uniselector to select from the cms.document table but you can't get it to join to the dedicated table for your chosen type. I think you're going to have to build a custom form control for this.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't believe this is possible with a Uni Selector, have you considered trying a List Box control instead? This one lets you define a SQL SELECT so you have full control over the data displayed. For example, set the *Data source* to be a **SQL Query** similar to this:

```
SELECT DocumentID, DocumentName, MyCustomField FROM dbo.Namespace_MyTable a
INNER JOIN dbo.CMS_Document b ON a.MyTableID = b.DocumentForeignKeyValue
INNER JOIN dbo.CMS_Tree c ON b.DocumentNodeID = c.NodeID AND c.NodeClassID = 1
-- Make sure NodeClassID has the correct value from dbo.CMS_Class
```

Then your *Text format* field can be something like **{%DocumentName%} {%MyCustomField%}**

I've tested this and it works. Might not suit your needs precisely but hopefully gets you closer than a uni selector is capable of.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add a UniGrid extender class to render that column and do a lookup on the value manually.

https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/creating-custom-modules/creating-extenders-for-module-interface-pages